# ORA-06550 in "IS NOT A SET"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to find duplicated values in a `ttXs`:

```
DECLARE
type invmXXs is table of inv_table.mobileId%type index by binary_integer;
ttXs                     invmXXs;
answer BOOLEAN;

BEGIN
-- out_exported_list is ref cursor
-- (...)
OPEN out_exported_list FOR
/* (....) */

FETCH out_exported_list
BULK COLLECT INTO ttXs;

answer := ttXs IS NOT A SET; -- ORA-06550
-- ...
END;
```

But I am getting ORA-06550 and I dont know why. How can I fix it?

> Error at line 1 ORA-06550: line 46, column 14: PLS-00306: wrong number
>   or types of arguments in call to 'MULTISET_UNION_DISTINCT' ORA-06550:
>   line 46, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov hope it helps

Comment: First of all. `IS A SET`  operator works with nested tables and you have declared there an associative array. Second. In PL/SQL elements of a nested table need to be of a scalar data type - not objects or records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a very simplified example in whcih you can try to handle/Find out Duplicate with nested tables. You are trying to achiev this by using Associative Array which doesnt support SET operations. Hope this helps.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
TYPE lv_var
IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
  v_tab lv_var;
  v1_tab lv_var;
BEGIN
  v_tab :=lv_var('a','a','b','c','d','d','e');
  v1_tab:=SET(v_tab);
  v1_tab:=SET(v_tab MULTISET
  EXCEPT v1_tab);
  FOR i IN v1_tab.FIRST..v1_tab.LAST
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(v1_tab(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: thanks for de suggestion. I will consider this to re-program my code